# How do you debug react-native when it is running on device?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do you debug react-native when it is running on device ?

Comment: Shake the device and then select `Debug remotely` in the popup. This would open a chrome window on the system. Then debug just like any javascript application.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Worked

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: By "device", you mean simulator? because you just accepted an answer that only works for simulator devices. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Debug remotely

iOS: Cmd + ctrl + z to open menu and select "Debug remotely"

Android: Cmd + M to open menu and select "Debug remotely"

2. Or run one of these commands:

   ```
   react-native log-ios
   react-native log-android
   ```

Answer (score 19):

Figured our React Native debugging for Android. Steps to for someone struggling with this -

1. Launch your RN App
2. Shake device
3. Select "Dev Settings"
4. Select "Debug server host & port for device" Put in your system's IP address.
5. Shake device
6. Select "Debug JS remotely"
7. Chrome will open a new tab with the address "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui"
8. If this doesn't happen, check your port and open a new tab and enter the above address with your port number.
9. Open #Chrome DevTools (Cmd+Alt+I on #MacOSX)
10. Select the Console Tab
11. Shake Device
12. Select "Reload"

View all your console logs or use "debugger;" in your JS for breakpoint debugging.

Comment: What is the systems ip address? Is it the public ip?

Comment: Yes it is the public IP

Comment: I think this only works when you build your app in the "Debug" configuration.

Answer (score 3):

There are little hack in here for IOS.
In XCode open AppDelegate.m from project folder, comment the line with jsCodeLocation declaration and add near it something like this:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://%YOUR_PC_IP%:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

, where %YOUR_PC_IP% is IP of your dev machine on local net.

Then open project named RCTWebSocket wich located in Libraries folder and then open from this project file RCTWebSocketProjectExecutor.m. Next, comment the line with host declaration, then add near it something like that:

```
host = @"%YOUR_PC_IP%";
```

Almost done. Run app on your device with XCode and make sure that your IPhone can see your develop machin via internet.

After it launches make sure that node server is running (command "react-native -- --start" in root project folder) and open via chrome this page: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui . Plus, option Debug JS Remotely must be enabled in your app on your IPhone. (Shake action, then tap in opened menu Debug JS Remotely, that is it.)

Now open dev console and have happy debugging.

Comment: Oh man I just use localtunnel to expose my dev server. Then I can develop without wires :)

Comment: Yes, you can use localtunnel endpoints instead of local IP, of course.

Comment: Only had to override the `jsCodeLocation`

Answer (score 3):

***2*** options exist:

### **Remote debug:** this would go over network, so it can be laggy.

1. Run app on device (install it whilst its plugged in)
2. Shake device (Android devices need to be **vigorously shaken**)
3. Press `settings` on the dev menu, and under `Debugging`, press `Debug server host and port for device`
4. Enter your debug server's IP address and port (usually 8081 unless you changed your settings of the debug server), e.g. 255.255.255.255:8081. Your ip address is the local IP address that your computer has. Ensure the device is on the same network. For mac users, open `System Preferences` → `Network` → `Wifi` → Under `Status: connected`, there is an IP address, use that.
5. You can unplug the device
6. Ensure debug mode is on (Shake device vigorously again, press Debug)

### Wired debug: relatively better for slow connections

1. Install app on phone
2. If android, set up port forwarding with `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and if iOS, follow the steps from [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools))
3. Enable debug on device

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on **Visual Studio Code** then you can install `React Native Tools` extension (provided by `Microsoft`) and debug your app like any other IDE.

Read all steps in detail in my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781/1055241).