# Debugging react native project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Can any one suggest me best plugins that available for **Visual Studio Code** for debugging react native app instead of chrome . Thanks in advance

Comment: [React Native Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.vscode-react-native) is by far the best plugin I have been using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `React Native Tools` extension (provided by `Microsoft`) to enable React Native app debugging in Visual Studio Code.

I have written steps to do so in detail in my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781/1055241).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **nodemon**, i think best suited. You can set according your needs

the **launch.json** part

> ```
>     {
>       "type": "node",
>       "request": "attach",
>       "name": "Node: Nodemon picker",
>       "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
>       "restart": true,
>       "protocol": "inspector",
>   },
> ```

i think chrome is not good environment for debugging in your case because it has generating extra codes while transforming

Answer (score 1):

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

This command could be helpful.