# How we can debug React-Native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

I am using google chrome for debugging the react native app but in the source code tab, I am not able to see .js files.
For debugging I am using physical device.

Any body know about the solution?
Is there any better method to debug the react native app?

Answer (score 2):

To debug a react-native app there is a react native debugger. It’s available on iOS and Windows as well. However, on Windows you have to download it manually from github. After you installed and started the debugger you can connect to it from the app emulator from the developer menu (command + d on iOS command + m in case of android emulator, on Windows you can use ctrl + m).

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Answer (score 0):

Curently, there's no react native debugger which can show you the .js files but you can debug the UI by this library: 
[https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools][1]

You can also config your IDE to jump to the source code by clicking on the error message by edditing your .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on **Visual Studio Code** and want to debug your React Native app just like all other IDEs, then you can take help from `React Native Tools` extension provided by `Microsoft`.

You can read all steps in detail in my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781/1055241).