# How can I debug React Native using only VSCode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I've see a few tutorials where a React Native app emulated on a physical Android device show the debug output directly to VSCode's debug console instead of the Debugger UI in Chrome. I've done it before and know it requires setting the debug server host and port in the Dev Settings menu once the app is launched, but I don't remember how I did it. Does anyone know the specific host and port number to input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you can follow the steps explained in the following link:

[Visual Studio Code Extension to debug application made with React Native](https://medium.com/@tunvirrahmantusher/react-native-debug-with-vscode-in-simple-steps-bf39b6331e67)

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. I was starting the packager in a console and not in VSCode. However, for future reference, React Native Tools is all you need. The Full Pack is somewhat bloated and contains tools that you might not need.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `React Native Full Pack`, you can also use `React Native Tools` extension provided by `Microsoft` and similarly you can debug react native app within VS Code itself.

[Read instructions in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781/1055241)