# How can I set up react native debugging in VS Code?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have read [this blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-react-native-vs-code/) and a number of SO answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781) that all detail how to set up debugging in VS Code, but after creating a debugging configuration for "Attach to packager" and running it, expo "refreshes" but blows by all the breakpoints. VS Code also is unable to see any of the variables or other debugging information:

[image: a screenshot of VS Code and the Android Studio device emulator displaying a non-functioning debugger]

[The Expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#debugging-with-vs-code) suggest using a completely different debugging plugin, but it is only available on SDK 49, which left beta 8 days ago. How do I get debugging to work with SDK 48 and the existing tools?