# Fetch request error on physical Android device in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I'm using `fetch()` to get some data from my server (running on my local machine).  When I run my React Native app in an Android emulator, it works fine.  But when I try to run it on my usb connected Android phone, it returns the error: `TypeError: Network request failed`. The host IP that I am trying to access from is set to `http://10.0.2.2:8080/`

Here's my fetch code:

```
    fetch(constants.HOST, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: "user=" + user
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        .....
    })
    .catch( err => console.log("fetch error",err));
```

I've seen a couple of answers suggest adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`  to the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I've added that but still get the error.

Edit: Note, the request doesn't return the error for up to two minutes.  It never throws the error straight away.

Comment: Have you tried any of the instructions here to debug the problem on the device? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415884/how-do-you-debug-react-native-when-it-is-running-on-device

Comment: is ```10.0.2.2``` reachable on phone?

Comment: What do you mean "reachable"?  Navigating there in a web browser?  While it's connected by USB?

Answer (score 0):

The ip address `10.0.2.2` is a special address representing the computer the emulator is running on when running in the Android Emulator.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

> 10.0.2.2  Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

So, when running on an actual device, this ip address is not valid. You need to make sure that the device and your server (your development machine) run in the same local network, then use the ip address of your server within that local network instead of `10.0.2.2`.

You also need to make sure that the server application (for example a node.js instance) is setup to accept connections from external computers (and not only from localhost), which means that it listens on `0.0.0.0` and not only on `localhost`. You also need to make sure there is no software firewall active on the server that would block connections from external computers.